# Why does std::clamp not work even when compiling with -std=c++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, clamp

I am changing to a new computer (windows), to which I pulled my project which used to work on my old laptop from the git. Unfortunately, the std::clamp function is not working when I try to execute the code now, even after specifying -std=c++17 in the execution.

Background: I am working with C++ in Visual Studio code (cpp standard set to c++17), MinGW compiler.  This produces the same error:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> // goniometry, sqrt
#include <algorithm> // clamp

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::clamp(2, 5, 17) << "\n";
}
```

I compile using `g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -std=c++17`

The error I get when running this is

```
PS C:\Users\Veren\OneDrive\Documents\Personal\Uni\Bsc3\BEP\Starting C++> g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o main.exe 
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:7:18: error: 'clamp' is not a member of 'std'
     std::cout << std::clamp(2, 5, 17) << "\n";
```

I also checked and my vscode has c++17 as a the cpp standard setting. Usually I would expect this error when compiling with an older c++ version, but I am not sure whether that is the issue now given I am explicitely telling it to use c++17. What could be other reasons for this error? Or is it possible it's not actually using c++17, and if so, what else should i do for this version to be used?

Comment: What version of MinGW are you using?

Comment: Not sure how to check that but doing `g++ --version` gives me `g++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0`
I only installed it last week so I'm hoping it's a new version

Comment: Looks like you need to update.  If it is really a fork of GCC 6.3 then this wont work as `std::clamp` wasn't supported by gcc until version 7.

Comment: You can see which versions of which compiler support specific features here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/17

Comment: ohhhh okay epic thank you I'll check that. Interesting though, since I just installed it, but if it's just that then that's doable. thank you!

Comment: Gcc 6.3 was released in December 2016 so is pretty old. I believe msys2 has more up to date releases or mingw64 https://www.mingw-w64.org/downloads/

Comment: @VerchaBercha There are two MinGW's out there.  A *old* one, probably the one your used, and MinGW64, which is a newer fork and uses a newer version of GCC

Comment: And the newer version should really be installed via MSYS2.

Comment: The official MinGW documentation for VSCode even tells you to use msys2 to install MinGW:  [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) If you followed the instructions you should have g++-12.2

Comment: I see that now msys2 has MinGW with gcc-13.1 by default: ***# g++ --version
g++.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.1.0***